# How could the vuejs app display the component at the location of the textarea cursor?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wanna create the vuejs component as following.
When typing in the `textarea`, the `textarea` has to show the recommended words.
For example, when the user typing `s`, it has to show the dorpdown list includes the words that starts with `s` at the location of the cursor of the  `textarea`.
Is this possible?
If possible, how could this be implemented?

Comment: Use `@input="myLookupFunc"` on your textarea. The `myLookupFunc` would search your words file/db for words starting/containing a substring starting after last whitespace and ending on your last typed character (use regex for that). Keep them in `words` property. Pass `words` as prop to your tooltip component. Display it if `words.length > 0`. The positioning is up to CSS.

Comment: If you find a js lib that already does this feature you can create a [directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) to use the lib with Vue

Comment: How could the app know the location of the cursor of the `textarea`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to detect the cursor position, but i had simulate your idea by using Vue.js and CSS and i reached to do that, you could improve it

```js
Vue.component('autocomplete', {
          data() {
  return {
   content: "",
   words: [
   "lorem",
   "ipsum",
   "dolor",
   "sit",
   "amet",
   "consectetur",
   "adipisicing",
   "elit"
   ],
   showAutoCompl:false
   
  };
 },
 computed: {
  contentWords(){
   return this.content.split(/ |\r|\r\n|\n/)
  }
  ,
  foundWords() {
   return this.words.filter(word => {
    return this.contentWords[this.contentWords.length-1] ? word.startsWith(this.contentWords[this.contentWords.length-1]) : "";
    
   });
  },
  lines(){
   return  this.content.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
  }

 },
 methods: {
  
  typeText(e) {
   
   this.content && this.foundWords.length?this.showAutoCompl=true:this.showAutoCompl=false;
   var div = document.getElementById("autocmpl");
   div.style.marginLeft = (10 + this.lines[this.lines.length-1].length * 7)+ "px";
   div.style.marginTop = ( this.lines.length * 8 )+ "px";
   
  },
  chooseWord(word){
     //    console.log(this.content.lastIndexOf("\n"))

     if(this.content.search("\n")===-1){
      this.content = this.content.substring(0,this.content.lastIndexOf(" ")+1)+ word;
     }else if(this.content.lastIndexOf(" ")>this.content.lastIndexOf("\n")) {
      this.content = this.content.substring(0,this.content.lastIndexOf(" ")+1)+ word;

     }else{
      this.content = this.content.substring(0,this.content.lastIndexOf("\n")+1)+ word;

     }
     this.showAutoCompl=false;
 }

},
  template: ` <div >
  <div class="autocomplete" id="autocmpl" v-show="showAutoCompl">
   <div class="autocomplete-item" v-for="word in foundWords" @click="chooseWord(word)">
    {{word}} 
   </div>
  </div>
  <textarea  @input="typeText" id="textarea1" cols="50" rows="10" v-model="content">
  </textarea>
 </div>
`
})



new Vue({
  el: "#app"
 
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


.autocomplete {
 margin: 0;
 margin-left: 10px;

 padding: 10px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #444;
 background: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
}
.autocomplete-item {
 padding: 5px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<autocomplete></autocomplete>
</div>
```

The following code is for single file component :

```js
<template>
 <div >
  <div class="autocomplete" id="autocmpl" v-show="showAutoCompl">
   <div class="autocomplete-item" v-for="word in foundWords" @click="chooseWord(word)">
    {{word}} 
   </div>
  </div>
  <textarea  @input="typeText" id="textarea1" cols="50" rows="10" v-model="content">
  </textarea>
 </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
 data() {
  return {
   content: "",
   words: [
   "lorem",
   "ipsum",
   "dolor",
   "sit",
   "amet",
   "consectetur",
   "adipisicing",
   "elit"
   ],
   showAutoCompl:false
   
  };
 },
 computed: {
  contentWords(){
   return this.content.split(/ |\r|\r\n|\n/)
  }
  ,
  foundWords() {
   return this.words.filter(word => {
    return this.contentWords[this.contentWords.length-1] ? word.startsWith(this.contentWords[this.contentWords.length-1]) : "";
    
   });
  },
  lines(){
   return  this.content.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
  }

 },
 methods: {
  
  typeText(e) {
   
   this.content && this.foundWords.length?this.showAutoCompl=true:this.showAutoCompl=false;
   var div = document.getElementById("autocmpl");
   div.style.marginLeft = (10 + this.lines[this.lines.length-1].length * 7)+ "px";
   div.style.marginTop = ( this.lines.length * 8 )+ "px";
   
  },
  chooseWord(word){
     //    console.log(this.content.lastIndexOf("\n"))

     if(this.content.search("\n")===-1){
      this.content = this.content.substring(0,this.content.lastIndexOf(" ")+1)+ word;
     }else if(this.content.lastIndexOf(" ")>this.content.lastIndexOf("\n")) {
      this.content = this.content.substring(0,this.content.lastIndexOf(" ")+1)+ word;

     }else{
      this.content = this.content.substring(0,this.content.lastIndexOf("\n")+1)+ word;

     }
     this.showAutoCompl=false;
 }

}
};
</script>

<style>
.autocomplete {
 margin: 0;
 margin-left: 10px;

 padding: 10px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #444;
 background: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
}
.autocomplete-item {
 padding: 5px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Comment: After typing multiple break line(\n), it doesn't shows at the correct location.

Comment: i couldn't a good way to set margin-top based in the number of lines

Comment: Isn't there a way to detect the cursor location of the text area?

Comment: unfortunately, no :( , i searched for long time but i didn't get a good way

Comment: i will try to improve

Comment: Thanks, Please update your answer for others if your find the better solutions.